# Can I use dried broad bean pods as mulch?

Tags: vegetables, mulch, beans

I had planted broad beans last year, and kept some pods on the vine until they dried out and turned black. I shelled them so now I have dried beans for planting later on, but this left me with quite a number of dried broad bean pods.

I've noticed they have an interesting texture, and I'm wondering whether they can be used as mulch, or perhaps there's some other use for them instead of just throwing everything in the garbage.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming theses pods are very dry and tough, If you can I would shred them,, then they would be ok as mulch.  if not, bury them deep in wet soil and turn into compost.  Don't waste your valuable plant matter if you can avoid it